# htaccess for subdomains

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to translate the example URL to the needed one?

```
From

http://test.at.domain.com

To

http://domain.com/at/index.php?id=test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\w+).at.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/at/index.php?id=%1 [L]
```

Comment: doesn't work. it says sorry this site is not currently available

Comment: What URL is it trying to send you to?  Is that the URL you expect?  If it is what you expect, then the problem isn't the .htaccess file but your site.  If it is not what you expect, then what is it that you expect?  You also need to say what you expect the %1 to do.

Comment: i honestly dont know how to use this type of regex i tried to derived it from another example. im guessing %1 is for {http_host} with the changes after but dont know

Comment: It's totally working for me.  When you say, "it says sorry this site is not currently available", is that showing up in the browser?  What is the URL the browser has in the location box?  And what is in your error_log?

Comment: do you need to set up something else in the website, besides setting up a wildcard in the A field as * ?

Comment: If you get rid of the .htaccess file altogether, do you get anything when you go to test.at.choosah.com?  If not, then you probably need to set something up for the site in one or more of your Apache configuration files.  This sort of stuff is probably better to ask over at serverfault.com than stackoverflow.com.